# PDO Binding Sequence/MySQL Incompatibility?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bind

I'm using MySQL(i)-community-5.3 if not mistaken. After finally getting the hang of PDO, I can now conclude that the infected sectore is that which processes binding, all other functions are fine (that I know of). Below I will present a function which works and also doesn't work (the sequence without anything to do with binding works flawlessly.

Function you() is as followes:

```
  public function you($row) {
   if(isset($_COOKIE["SK"])) {
    $usr = $this->baseXencode($_SESSION["username"]);
    $q = "SELECT $row FROM SN_users WHERE username=:USR";
    $this->netCore->q($q);
    $this->netCore->bind(":USR", $usr);
    $result = $this->netCore->single();
    $result = $result[$row];
   } else {
    $q = "SELECT $row FROM SN_users WHERE username='".$this->baseXencode("Anonymous")."' AND password='".$this->baseXencode("Anonymous")."'";
    $result = $this->netCore->q($q);
    $result = $this->netCore->single();
    $result = $result[$row];
   }
   return $result;
  }
 }
```

(As you can see, when pre-allocating the username/password combo for Anonymous users, the function executes perfectly whereas binding within the if() section does not, returning the value 1.

Below is my binding function `bind()` (if you may require any other code, I will edit this post further~^^):

**EDIT:**

Below is the netCore class:

```
 class netCore {
  private $boot;
  private $dbHost = "";
  private $dbNAME = "";
  private $dbPASS = "";
  private $dbUSR = "";
  private $err;
  private $state;
  public function __construct() {
   $bootloadr = "mysql:host=".$this->dbHost.";dbname=".$this->dbNAME.";charset=UTF8";
   $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   try {
    $this->boot = new PDO($bootloadr, $this->dbUSR, $this->dbPASS, $opt);
   } catch(PDOException $e) {
    $this->err = "<b>Lebensborn&reg; netCore&trade; Error:</b> An exception has been raised during Network-to-Database procedures.<br /><b>Message:</b> ".$e->getMessage().".";
   }
  }
  public function bind($param, $value, $type = NULL) {
   if(is_null($type)) {
    switch(true) {
     case is_int($value):
      $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
     break;
     case is_bool($value):
      $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
     break;
     case is_null($value):
      $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
     break;
     default:
      $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
    }
   }
   $this->state->bindParam($param, $value, $type);
  }
  public function debug() {
   return $this->state->debugDumpParams();
  }
  public function exe() {
   return $this->state->execute();
  }
  public function count() {
   $this->exe();
   return $this->state->fetchColumn();
  }
  public function q($q) {
   $this->state = $this->boot->prepare($q);
  }
  public function set() {
   $this->exe();
   return $this->state->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
  public function single() {
   $this->exe();
   return $this->state->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
  public function transBegin() {
   return $this->boot->beginTransaction();
  }
  public function transCancel() {
   return $this->boot->rollBack();
  }
  public function transEnd() {
   return $this->boot->commit();
  }
 }
```

Comment: We would need, at very least, to see the definitions of the `$this->netCore` object's `q()` and `single()` methods.  Don't post them as answer: simply [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21001668/edit).

Comment: Post edited with the requested code.^^

Comment: Now we're just getting lost in a whole quagmire of function calls.  We need to understand how you are ultimately interfacing with PDO.  What is `$this->state`?  What is `$this->boot`?  What are their respective `fetch()` and `prepare()` methods?  What is `$this->exe()`?  As things stand, we have absolutely no idea what is going on.

Comment: Revised at your request~^^

Comment: Because `PDOStatement::bindParam()` binds by reference, I suppose that the `$value` to which it has bound is no longer in scope once your `netCore::bind()` function returns.  You could either make that function argument pass by reference, e.g. `public function bind($param, &$value, $type = NULL) {` or use `PDOStatement::bindValue()` instead.